# I tried to make a simple application to let my phone vibrate

Tags: android, vibration, android-vibration

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Vibrator;
Context context;
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATE_SERVICE);

void setup(){}

void draw(){
  v.vibrate(1000);
  noLoop();
}
```

PS. I gave the permissions for vibrate through the settings

So what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: where you are initializing your **context**

Comment: try this   Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) 
             getActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
             vibrator.vibrate(100);

Comment: Thank u for ur help now its finally working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
 Vibrator v = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
```

instead of this

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATE_SERVICE);
```

> **NOTE :**
>   Don't forgot to initialize your `context`

**UPDATE**

**`Vibrator.vibrate()`** is deprecated

use this

```
void draw(){

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
            v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(1000, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
        } else {
            v.vibrate(1000);
        }
    }
```

**Sample code**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.VibrationEffect;
import android.os.Vibrator;

public class Tester
{
    Context context;
    Vibrator vibrator;

    public Tester(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    }




    void setup(){}

    void draw(){

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
            vibrator.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(150, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
        } else {
            vibrator.vibrate(150);
        }
    }
}
```

call this method like this

```
Tester tester= new Tester(this);
tester.draw();
```

Comment: I made the class as u told me to, but I got some Problems:

Comment: @W4hrsch3inlich what problems

Comment: if i try to let this programm running i'm getting the error, that i cant make this tester class + the programm is arguing with the "VibrationEffect"

Comment: make class name as per your choice @W4hrsch3inlich

Comment: Ok, but there are still problems with the VibrationEffect.(i cant import android.os.VibrationEffect)

Comment: what problem @W4hrsch3inlich

Comment: @W4hrsch3inlich import **`import android.os.VibrationEffect;`** check my updated ans

Comment: @W4hrsch3inlich its working fine my device than just use simple **vibrator.vibrate(150);**.

Comment: @W4hrsch3inlich did you import this **`import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.VibrationEffect;
import android.os.Vibrator`**

Comment: @W4hrsch3inlich you can accept this ans by click on TICK sign

Comment: @W4hrsch3inlich you can accept this ans see this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png

Comment: xD seems im blind

Comment: @W4hrsch3inlich hahaha lol happy to help you keep enjoy codding